# Returning the name of an entries own column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table, the first column is called "names" and the second column is called "ages".  For example,

Names...Age
John......45
Mary......32
Alan......20

I want the data to be formatted such that the column name is put in front of each entry, i.e.

Names...............Age
Names John......Age 45
Names Mary......Age 32
Names Alan......Age 20

How can I perform such a task?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, but I should have elaborated more, what if I don't necessarily know the names of the columns?  Let's say I imported 10 different tables all with different column names?

Comment: Again I would ask....why in the world would you want to do this? It will require dynamic sql and will not work for every datatype.

Comment: Assume I get 10 lists of customers.  But each list has different headers.  Some might say "name", some might say "cust name", some might say "cust ID" etc.  Previously, we had a master list of customers, and at the time of importing, each INSERT statement was tailored to that specific list we were importing.  So 10 different lists, 10 different forms of the INSERT statement.  This way I'm doing, we load everything in with the column name, and then later, have SQL scan the table, and anything that has "cust ID", or "cust num" etc gets sorted into the proper column.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad design to me. Why not have a column that indicates the "type" of row instead of bastardizing each and every value? If you are stuck with this you are going to have to use dynamic sql to build your select statements so you can append the column name in front of the actual data. This is just horribly redundant. If you have 10,000 rows with 50 columns you have created 500,000 duplicate strings in your data to hold the column names they will eventually end up in. And of course you have to use dynamic sql on the other end to split this back out.

Comment: "Why not have a column that indicates the "type" of row instead of bastardizing each and every value?"  

Can you elaborate on that further? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: What you are doing is changing the value of every single row and column. You could instead add a column to your table that indicates the type of row it is so you know which of your insert statements to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat('Names',' ',Names),concat('Age',' ',Age) from tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select 'Names ' + Names as name, 'Age ' + cast(Age as nvarchar) from myTable
```